# Chart not shown in Vue, error shows: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: nextDatasets.map is not a function

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I'm building a weather app to show data in line chart with Vue Vite and vue-chartjs. Data, options and plugins are all customized. I'm now stuck with conditions when data passed in with props (I have checked data before), it did not show charts on page (only show <canvas> with no children tags). And I tried to render charts after getting data, but not work either.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbT1x.png)

```
<template>
    <div v-if="hasData">
        <Line :data="data" :options="options" :plugins="plugins" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { getIconUrl } from '../../assets/js/getIconUrl.js';
import { getGradient, externalTooltipHandler } from '../charts/ChartActions.js';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { hours } from '../charts/ChartActions.js';

import { computed, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs';
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    Filler,
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    Filler
);

const props = defineProps({
    weatherData: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
        default: {},
    },
    currentTimeIndex: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0,
    },
    sunrisesData: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
        default: {},
    },
});

const hourlyTempData = ref(null);
const minOfTemp = ref(null);
const maxOfTemp = ref(null);

hourlyTempData.value = computed(() =>
    props.weatherData?.map((data) => data.temp_fc)
);
minOfTemp.value = computed(() => Math.min(...hourlyTempData));
maxOfTemp.value = computed(() => Math.max(...hourlyTempData));

const hasData = ref(false);
const labelChart = hours();
const palette = [
    {
        hex: '#fff',
        rgba1: 'rgba(255,255,255,.05)',
        rgba2: 'rgba(255,255,255,.2)',
    },
    {
        hex: '#74a57f',
        rgba: 'rgba(116, 165, 127,.8)',
    },
    {
        hex: '#077187',
        rgba: 'rgba(7, 113, 135,.2)',
    },
    {
        hex: '#000',
        rgba: 'rgba(0,0,0,.15)',
    },
];

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// -----------    CHART DATA   -------------
const data = {
    labels: labelChart,
    datasets: {
        data: hourlyTempData.value,
        backgroundColor: (context) => {
            const chart = context.chart;
            const { ctx, chartArea } = chart;
            if (!chartArea) return;
            const color1 = palette[1].rgba;
            const color2 = palette[2].rgba;
            return getGradient(ctx, chartArea, {
                color1,
                color2,
            });
        },
        borderColor: (context) => {
            const chart = context.chart;
            const { ctx, chartArea } = chart;
            if (!chartArea) return;
            const color1 = palette[1].hex;
            const color2 = palette[2].hex;
            return getGradient(ctx, chartArea, {
                color1,
                color2,
            });
        },
        borderWidth: 6,
        pointBorderColor: '#0E1428',
        hoverBackgroundColor: palette[0].hex,
        tension: 0.4,
        fill: true,
    },
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// -----------   CHART OPTIONS   -------------
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
        padding: { top: 30, bottom: 5, right: 15 }, 
    },
    interaction: {
        intersect: false,
        mode: 'index',
    },
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false,
            position: 'nearest',
            external: externalTooltipHandler,
            callbacks: {
                label(tooltipItem) {
                    const value = tooltipItem.raw + '°';
                    return value;
                },
            },
        },
    },
    scales: {
        x: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom',
            border: {
                dash: [2, 2],
            },
            ticks: {
                callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
                    if (index % 6 === 0) return this.getLabelForValue(index);
                },
                align: 'inner',
            },
            grid: {
                color: palette[0].rgba1,
            },
        },
        x1: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top',
            grid: {
                display: false,
            },
            ticks: {
                display: false,
                align: 'inner',
            },
        },
        y: {
            position: 'right',
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 3,
                callback: (value) => {
                    return value + '°';
                },
            },
            grace: '10%',
            grid: {
                color: palette[0].rgba1,
            },
        },
    },
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// -----------   CHART PLUGINS    -------------

// PLUGIN: init chart
const init_temp = {
    id: 'init_temp',
    afterInit(chart) {
        const datasets = chart.data.datasets[0];
        const { data } = datasets;
        const currentTimeIndex = currentTimeIndex.value;

        // initialize
        datasets.pointBackgroundColor = [];
        datasets.pointRadius = [];
        datasets.pointBorderWidth = [];

        // show points of max and min, and point of today
        const maxIndex = data.findIndex((data) => data === maxOfTemp.value);
        const minIndex = data.findIndex((data) => data === minOfTemp.value);

        for (let i = 0; i < data?.length; i++) {
            if (i !== maxIndex && i !== minIndex && i !== currentTimeIndex) {
                datasets.pointRadius[i] = 0;
                datasets.pointBorderWidth[i] = 0;
            } else {
                datasets.pointBackgroundColor[i] =
                    i === currentTimeIndex ? palette[0].hex : 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
                datasets.pointRadius[i] = 4;
                datasets.pointBorderWidth[i] = 3;
            }
        }

        chart.init_temp = { maxIndex, minIndex, currentTimeIndex };
    },
    beforeDraw(chart) {
        const { maxIndex, minIndex, currentTimeIndex } = chart.init;
        const {
            ctx,
            canvas: { clientLeft: left, clientTop: top, clientHeight: height },
        } = chart;
        const x = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[currentTimeIndex]?.x;
        ctx.save();

        // show point labels of max and min
        ctx.fillStyle = '#bbb';
        ctx.font = '14px';
        const textWidth = ctx.measureText('max').width;

        ctx.fillText(
            'max',
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[maxIndex]?.x - textWidth / 2,
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[maxIndex]?.y - 10
        );

        ctx.fillText(
            'min',
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[minIndex]?.x - textWidth / 2,
            chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[minIndex]?.y - 10
        );

        // fill regtangle for past time
        ctx.fillStyle = palette[3].rgba;
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.fillRect(left, top, x, height);
        ctx.restore();

        // draw line for current time
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(x, height);
        ctx.strokeStyle = palette[0].rgba2;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    },
};

// PLUGIN: show vertical line on hover
const tooltipLine = {
    id: 'tooltipLine',
    afterInit(chart) {
        chart.tooltipLine = {};
    },
    afterEvent(chart, args) {
        const { inChartArea } = args;
        const { x } = args.event;
        chart.tooltipLine = { draw: inChartArea, x };

        chart.draw();
    },
    beforeDraw(chart) {
        const { draw, x } = chart.tooltipLine;
        const { ctx } = chart;
        const { bottom } = chart.chartArea;
        ctx.save();

        if (!draw) return;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(x, bottom);
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle = palette[0].hex;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    },
};

// PLUGIN: show chart border
const chartAreaBorder = {
    id: 'chartAreaBorder',
    afterDatasetsDraw(chart) {
        const {
            ctx,
            canvas: { clientLeft, clientTop, clientWidth, clientHeight },
        } = chart;

        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeRect(clientLeft, clientTop, clientWidth, clientHeight);
        ctx.strokeStyle = palette[0].rgba1;
        ctx.restore();
    },
};

// PLUGIN: Get icon on x axis
const labellingIconOnXAxis = {
    id: 'labellingIconOnXAxis',
    afterDraw: (chart) => {
        const { ctx } = chart;
        const datasets = chart.data.datasets[0];
        const { data } = datasets;
        for (let i = 0; i < data?.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) % 2 === 0) {
                const pointEl = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[i];
                let image = new Image();
                image.src = getIconUrl(
                    {
                        sunrisesData: props.sunrisesData,
                        weatherData: props.weatherData[i],
                    },
                    true
                );
                ctx.drawImage(image, pointEl.x - 20, 0, 40, 40);
            }
        }
    },
};

const plugins = [chartAreaBorder, init_temp, tooltipLine, labellingIconOnXAxis];

onMounted(() => {
    try {
        if (
            !props.currentTimeIndex ||
            !props.weatherData ||
            !props.sunrisesData
        )
            return;
        hasData.value = true;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
});
```

I expected to show charts when page load and changes when select one dropdown-menu item. Thank you very much in advance if someone could help figure out the problem.